# NSwag.CodeGeneration.TypeScript marks all reference types as nullable

Tags: c#, typescript, nswag

I'm using `NSwag.CodeGeneration.TypeScript` in a .NET 6 application to generate a file with types for the front end in TypeScript.

This is my code:

```cs
var settings = new TypeScriptClientGeneratorSettings
{
    GenerateClientClasses = false
};
settings.TypeScriptGeneratorSettings.TypeStyle = TypeScriptTypeStyle.Interface;
settings.TypeScriptGeneratorSettings.TypeScriptVersion = 3.5M;
settings.TypeScriptGeneratorSettings.DateTimeType = TypeScriptDateTimeType.String;

var generator = new TypeScriptClientGenerator(document, settings);

var code = generator.GenerateFile();
```

My problem is that every reference type is converted to a nullable, even if it isn't. No problems with nullable value types.

I tried using this:

```cs
settings.TypeScriptGeneratorSettings.MarkOptionalProperties = false;
```

But now all nullable properties (even value types) are not marked as nullables.
Can I turn off marking reference types as nullables in the resulting TypeScript?

Comment: When you say they are not marked as nullables, do you mean optional or nullable? `x?: number` (optional) and `x: number | null` (nullable) is not the same.

Comment: I consider both `| undefined` and `?: string` as a problem I'm tackling.